# How can I access the property of a class in C# from Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, generics, vb6, com-interop

I need help in the above topic. I have done everything required for my VB6 application to work with a C# dll. I got to a point where I am unable to access the property of a class to obtain the ID.

I am calling this C# function:

```
public resultRetrieveWIP RetrieveWIP(string serialNumber)
{
     string header = string.Format("Bearer {0}", User.Token);

     var request = new RestRequest();
     request.Method = Method.GET;
     request.Resource = "api/wips";
     request.AddParameter("serialNumber", serialNumber);
     request.AddHeader("Authorization", header);

     var client = new RestClient(_iFactoryURL);
     var response = client.Execute(request);
     var uri = client.BuildUri(request);
     _lastRequest = uri.ToString();
     _lastResponse = response.Content;

     try
     {
          var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore };
          return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<resultRetrieveWIP>(response.Content,settings);
     }
     catch
     {
          throw new Exception(jsonErrorHandler("RetrieveWIP",response.Content));
     }
}
```

resultRetrieveWIP has type as follows:

```
    public class resultRetrieveWIP
    {
        public List<wip> wips { get; set; }
    }

    public class wip
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
    }
```

In my Visual Basic, I added the above CIMiFactory.dll as my reference then I do this:

```
Public oIFactory As New CIMiFactory.iFactory

Public Function iFactory_GetSubAssySN(ByVal strSerialNumber As String, ByVal strPartNumber As String) As String
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim getWIP As New CIMiFactory.resultRetrieveWIP
    Dim wip As New CIMiFactory.wip
    iFactory_GetSubAssySN = ""

    Set getWIP = oIFactory.RetrieveWIP(strSerialNumber)

    **Set wip = getWIP.wips(0)**
    iFactory_GetSubAssySN = CStr(wip.id)

    Exit Function

errHandler:
    iFactory_GetSubAssySN = Err.Description
End Function
```

**I have problem at the line code marked ** **.**

It gave error.

> "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

What is the correct method to get the "id" property value?.

Comment: VB6 != VBScript.

Comment: As your c# code dll required **RestSharp**, **json newtonsoft**  libs into your vb6 project. But these lib not support VB6 environments as per my knowledge. You are trying to go back with latest technology to old tech environments.

Comment: All the other functions can work without problem. There is even a login function which will return a token and it works fine. VB will just call the class functions and C# will implement the RestSharp and json methods. However, I don't think this is the issue here. Let me rephrase my question, gIven a basic C# code, what is the correct method to access the property of a type class from VB?

Comment: can you tell me what object you get in 'Set getWIP = oIFactory.RetrieveWIP(strSerialNumber)'

Answer (score 2):

[Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/) are not supported in VB6, so you can't access `List(Of T)` items, which is what `getWIP.wips(0)` is doing. You can use a non-generic **Collection** instead, in your `resultRetrieveWIP` class:

```
public class resultRetrieveWIP
{
    public Collection wips { get; set; }
}
```

See the following article for more details: [How To Use a .NET Class with Lists in VB6](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32364/How-To-Use-a-NET-Class-with-Lists-in-VB6)

Answer (score 2):

As [Étienne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59158859/3195477) has said, generics cannot be exported to COM.

One option is to add a separate `IEnumerable` "wrapper" property just to be accessible through COM, like so:

```
public class resultRetrieveWIP
{
    public List<wip> wips { get; set; }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public IEnumerable GetWipsCOM() => wips;
}
```

This way code internal to C# can use the correct fully-typed generic list without any changes, and VB6 or whatever other COM consumer can also access the data.

`IEnumerable` is supported by COM & VB6. ie you would be able to `For Each` through the result of `GetWipsCOM()` in VB6.